# Tomcat 8 can't see MySQL Driver

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, driver, tomcat8

I have tried to migrate my application container from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8, but it seems that Tomcat 8 can't find the JDBC driver. The application uses Spring 4 and Vaadin 7, but this shouldn't cause any problems I think.

When I check the exploded jar I have under `/WEB-INF/lib` the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar` which is put there using Apache Maven.

I can only make tomcat 8 see the jar just by adding it manually under `tomcat-home/lib` folder, which I don't want to do. I want the flexibility to choose the type of driver and its version from Maven.

I think it may be a timing issue, maybe the jar hasn't been loaded yet and tomcat can't find it. The error I get is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

I'd really appreciate and hints and suggestions. If it's a timing issue do you know what I should try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Tomcat JDBC connection pool? If so, you might want to give Tomcat 8.0.5 a try when it comes out. Prior to 8.0.5, Tomcat JDBC is not able to load JDBC driver classes packaged in webapps.

See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/201403.mbox/%3c532F30D2.1040209@apache.org%3e

Answer (score 1):

Download mysql connector file `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`, place that file in your lib folder, and restart tomcat and run. I had same issue and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have read a Tomcat document somewhere, in their pages, it states that DB drivers should not be packaged with your application.
Because, even if it is there it will not be added to its classpath with the default configuration.

Otherwise edit you catalina.properties and remove JDBC driver references.

Or as you can put them in the home or base.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to database in web application with tomcat : you should add database-driver jars to tomcat lib folder and enlarge tomcat memory used